# Keydown event for entire application VB .Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, keydown

I want to make it so that no matter which control has focus, it will do my event. So that I dont have to write a keydown event for all 137 of my objects. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Be aware that if it wasn't possible via the form's KeyPreview, you could simply recursively-loop through the form's controls and assign an event to the controls at run time. Events, so long as they have the same signature, are easily reused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the **[KeyPreview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx)** property of your Form to *True*.

> *When this property is set to true, the
>   form will receive all  KeyPress, 
>   KeyDown, and  KeyUp events.*

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert but I believe this is possible. I've done it before where I've had one event handler handle multiple button presses, and then do something different depending on which button has focus.

The code is for that is something like:

```
For Each ctl in Me.Controls
If ctl.Type is <whatever type of control you want to handle> And ctl.Isfocused Then
Do whatever
End If
Next
```

You don't need to worry about recursion for something like that.

It's easier if you want each control to do the same thing, no matter which one has focus.

```
Private Sub keypresshandle (System arguments ignore this) Handles key1.press, key2.press etc .... key10000.press
do some stuff here
End Sub
```